# How to integrate Ant with Checkstyle and PMD plug-ins in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, checkstyle, pmd

I want to integrate Checkstyle and PMD plug-ins in Jenkins for checking quality code automatically.
I followed the instructions from: http://www.treselle.com/blog/static-code-analysis-jenkins/

My build.xml in workspace was appended those codes:

```
<taskdef name="checkstyle" classpath="WEB-INF/libs/checkstyle-5.6.jar" classname="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.CheckStyleTask" />
<target name="checkstyle" description="Generates a report of code convention violations.">
    <checkstyle config="sun_checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
        <formatter type="xml" tofile="checkstyle_report.xml" />
        <fileset dir="WEB-INF/src" includes="**/*.java" />
    </checkstyle>
</target>
<taskdef name="pmd" classpath="WEB-INF/libs/pmd.jar" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" />
<target name="pmd" depends="compress">
    <pmd rulesetfiles="java-imports">
        <formatter type="xml" toFile="pmd_report.x.ml" />
        <fileset dir="WEB-INF/src">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </pmd>
</target>
```

I also added enough library, but when I builded Jobs, I got a exception:

```
taskdef class com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.CheckStyleTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
```

Why is there such error? And How do I integrate them correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try later version of check style as checkstyle-8.0-all.jar.
See [example](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html)

Answer (score 0):

> classname="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.CheckStyleTask" />
>   taskdef class com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.CheckStyleTask cannot be found

The class is named `CheckstyleAntTask`.

See https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/config/ant-phase-verify.xml on an example on how to use `CheckstyleAntTask`.

> checkstyle-5.6.jar

I recommend upgrading to a newer version. Checkstyle is currently on version 8.